# Enthalpy as a differential function of Gibbs energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, calculus

I am trying to find a first order differential relation between Enthalpy $H$ and Gibbs free energy $G$ which should look like
$H=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}\right)_{Y}$.

I tried an could only reach $\left(\frac{d H}{d T}\right)_{P}=-T\left(\frac{d^{2} G}{d T^{2}}\right)_{P}$.

I'm unable to move forward,could anyone please show me how to move ahead? Thank you.

Comment: What is d(G/T)/d(1/T) equal to?

Comment: Thank you dear Chet Miller, I found it's equal to $H$ ?